# Binding Master Detail data to XtraReport Winforms DevExpress Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, master-detail, xtrareport

Am trying to bind data (Master Details) to XtraReport programmatic. If **Master** is single data/values means **XtraReport** working fine. But in my case **Master** is  multiple data/values, here all **Details** data is prints on all **Masters**.

eg. **(Vehicle Report)** - Here 1)Cars & 2)Bikes are Master, Details of Cars Master is **BMW, Datsun, Hyundai**. Details of Bike Master is **Honda, Moto, Yamaha**. Now I want to print like this

```
Report

Cars
   BMW
   Datsun
   Hyundai

Bikes
   Honda
   Moto
   Yamaha
```

but it printing like this

```
Report 

Cars
   BMW
   Datsun
   Hyundai
   Honda
   Moto
   Yamaha

Bikes
   BMW
   Datsun
   Hyundai
   Honda
   Moto
   Yamaha
```

Already I place Labels in designer XtraReports. This is my code to prints data on XtraReports programmatic

```
private void Report1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StrConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.DataPath + @"CMDB\database.mdb";

            string qry2 = "SELECT chequeid AS ChqBukId, chdescri AS ChqBukDesc, (SELECT bankname FROM tblBankMaster WHERE bank_id=tbchequebook.bankID) AS BankName FROM tbchequebook";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry2, StrConnection);
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            adapter1.Fill(ds1, "Detail");
            ds1.Tables[0].TableName = "QryBank";
            DetailReport.DataSource = ds1;

            XRBinding bindingBankName = new XRBinding("Text", ds1, "QryBank.BankName");
            TXE_BankName.DataBindings.Add(bindingBankName);
            XRBinding bindingchqbukame = new XRBinding("Text", ds1, "QryBank.ChqBukDesc");
            TXE_ChequeBookDesc.DataBindings.Add(bindingchqbukame);

            string qry4 = "SELECT chq_no, chq_date, party_name, chq_amount FROM tblchequeleafnew WHERE Status='P' ";

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry4, StrConnection);
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            adapter3.Fill(ds3, "Detail2");
            ds3.Tables[0].TableName = "QryCheque";
            DetailReport1.DataSource = ds3;

            XRBinding bindingChqNo = new XRBinding("Text", ds3, "QryCheque.chq_no");
            TXE_ChequeNo.DataBindings.Add(bindingChqNo);

            XRBinding bindingChqDate = new XRBinding("Text", ds3, "QryCheque.chq_date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            TXE_ChequeDate.DataBindings.Add(bindingChqDate);

            XRBinding bindingPartyName = new XRBinding("Text", ds3, "QryCheque.party_name");
            TXE_PartyName.DataBindings.Add(bindingPartyName);

            XRBinding bindingChqAmt = new XRBinding("Text", ds3, "QryCheque.chq_amount", "{0:N2}");
            TXE_ChequeAmount.DataBindings.Add(bindingChqAmt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessagebox.Show(ex.message.tostring());
        }
    }
```

This is my XtraReport

[image: XtraReport]

How to solve this to get exact Master & Its Details. Using this above code am getting Master exactly, but it show all details under all masters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up relations between your master and details levels.
If you are using `DataSet` then you need to use one `DataSet` object for all `DataSource` members and `DataSet.Relations` collection to create the relations between your tables. Also you need to use the relation name as `DetailReport.DataMember` property and use the same relation name in bindings.
Here is example:
[image: Report design]

```
private void XtraReport1_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    var vehicleTypes = new DataTable("VehicleTypes");
    vehicleTypes.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));

    vehicleTypes.Rows.Add("Cars");
    vehicleTypes.Rows.Add("Bikes");

    var vehicles = new DataTable("Vehicles");
    vehicles.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
    vehicles.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    vehicles.Rows.Add("Cars", "BMW");
    vehicles.Rows.Add("Cars", "Datsun");
    vehicles.Rows.Add("Cars", "Hyundai");
    vehicles.Rows.Add("Bikes", "Honda");
    vehicles.Rows.Add("Bikes", "Moto");
    vehicles.Rows.Add("Bikes", "Yamaha");

    var dataSet = new DataSet("Data");

    dataSet.Tables.Add(vehicleTypes);
    dataSet.Tables.Add(vehicles);
    dataSet.Relations.Add("VehiclesRelation", vehicleTypes.Columns["Type"], vehicles.Columns["Type"]);

    DataSource = dataSet;

    vehicleTypeLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSet, "Type");

    VehicleDetailReport.DataMember = "VehiclesRelation";
    vehicleLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSet, "VehiclesRelation.Name");
}
```